# promise chain resolves before its last promise resolves

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

**Background**
Started with 2 nearly identical javascripts then refactored into 3: a utility script containing formerly redundant code + 2 calling scripts.

**Problem**
The two original scripts use jquery Deferreds (when.then) and work fine.  The 3-script scenario fails because the next-to-last **promise resolves early** from one calling script.

**Details**
The first script, call it "multi" uses a sequence of deferreds to loop through a series of ajax requests and then refreshes the "multi" page in the browser.  So:

`auth -> user -> loop (updateIssue -> transition) end loop -> refresh`

The 2nd, "single" uses effectively the same code without the loop, and then a different `refresh` function

My aim was to refactor the code into a promise chain in a utility script and use like so:

```
// calling script
Utility.promiseChain().done(refresh())

// utility script
Utility.promiseChain = function() {
return authPromise()
.then(function() { return userPromise();} )
.then(function() { return Promise.all(array of update.then(transition) promises);})}
```

**The Problem, More Specifically**
The Promise.all call ALWAYS resolves after `update`, but before `transition`, causing the `refresh` to fire early, followed by the `transition`. Any insight you can provide will be most helpful.

Comment: Could you please show the code that creates the array of `update.then(transition)` promises, what the `transition` onFullfilled handler does and what version of JQuery you are using - versions 1 and 2 are not compliant with promise standards and have problems dealing with native Promises accurately.

Comment: Also, besides the version, what kind of promises do `authPromise` and `userPromise` return,  ES6 or JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

> The Promise.all call ALWAYS resolves after update, but before transition

The only way that can happen is if something in your chain of events is not properly chaining promises.  You will have to show us the real code for us to help you identify the specific problem, but if `Promise.all()` is not waiting for a `transition` promise, then that promise must not be properly chained into the array of promises that `Promise.all()` is waiting on.

Specifically, we need to see the code behind this part of your pseudo-code:

```
array of update.then(transition) promises
```

to see exactly how `transition()` is involved in creating that array of promises. 
 As always, if you show us your REAL code rather than just pseudo-code, we can help find the source of the actual error in programming logic.

Comment: @varontron - Is your question answered yet?

Answer (score 0):

A possible scenario is that you are using JQuery < version 3, and the call to `authPromise()` returns a JQuery promise. This would mean all the promises returned by `then` in the promise chain returned by `Utility.promiseChain` are JQuery promises. The last time I checked, older versions of JQuery do not recognize foreign library promises, including those returned by native Promise constructors, as a promise and will **fulfill** a JQuery promise resolved with one without waiting for it to be settled.

It is possible that the promise object returned by `Promise.all` in

```
.then(function() { return Promise.all( // ...
```

is being used to fulfill the promise returned by `then` without waiting for it to be settled.

In short you can't resolve an older version of JQuery promise with an ES6 promise and produce the effect of resolving a promise with a promise.

Potential solutions:

1. Upgrade to JQuery 3 (you lose support for old versions of IE but these don't support `Promise` anyway). Recommended if you can do it.
2. Convert all promise usage to ES6 style promises and convert any JQuery promises that are being passed around to ES6 promises before use by calling  `Promise.resolve( jqPromise)`
3. Write the equivalent of `Promise.resolve` in reverse to convert an ES6 promise into a JQuery promise. I would rate this as possible but a huge hack backwards in the wrong direction.